# Is there a way to display scraped data as webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to display only the scraped data of a particular website.

Like webscraper.io (Chrome extension) scrapes data and displays the site with only the required data.

Is there a way to do so using python ?

Comment: Sure. Print the html elements out to a file

Comment: you can `print()` it and you will see it. You can save in file and open in standard browser ie. `webbrowser.open(filename)`. You can build own GUI with PyQt WebKit widget and display in this widget.